# Why process output reader returns null data? When same code in other process works correct

Tags: c#, cmd, ffmpeg, process, output

I try to get output from ffmpeg process but cant get output.
In another processes and commands it works correctly but output returns immideately when start!

```
        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = LinkHelper.IPFS_PATH,
                Arguments = cmd,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            };

            process.ErrorDataReceived += FfmpegErrorRecieved;
            process.Start();

            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string output = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(output);
            }               
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
```

[Before output handle!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdQku.png)

Update:
As szatmary said ffmpeg use output error instead standard output, so when you initialize process.StandartInfo don't forget initialize property "RedirectStandardError" to TRUE!

Here is correct code:

```
private async Task DetectFFmpegCamerasAsync()
    {
        var cmd = "-list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy";
        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = LinkHelper.FFMPEG_PATH,
                Arguments = cmd,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true
            };

            process.Start();

            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardError)
            {
                string output = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Camera detection output: \n {output}");
            }               
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ffmpeg` writes its output to `stderr` and not `stdout`.
Therefore you must read from [standard error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror?view=netframework-4.8) instead of standard out.

So use the following lines instead:

```
using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardError)
{
    string output = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Comment: Agree to disagree. I believe the user is smart enough to use this information to fix the issue.

Comment: Agreed. But then your answer would have been missing the appropriate code sample to show this difference. So I edited your answer. I hope that you agree with the edit.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
process.Start();
```

Add

```
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```